# a2enmod throwing an error: "BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/a2enmod line 15."

Tags: apache, compiler-errors, a2enmod

I have an apache server installed on a Raspbian 10.

I am trying to enable some modules, but a2enmod is throwing a compilation error.

Apache is up to date, and no one else seems to have this issue online. I'm honestly not sure what to do.

Here is the command/result:
(Please note that the result is the same no matter which module I try to enable, or no module at all)

pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2 $ a2enmod
Can't locate if.pm in @INC (you may need to install the if module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.28 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.28 /usr/share/perl/5.28 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl-base) at /usr/sbin/a2enmod line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/a2enmod line 15.